# keyboard log for reference

Tags: android

I want to write an application that will log down whatever I type using the Android keyboard.

The purpose is to have a backup of all the keyboard entries.

Is it possible?

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible. You can use Log.v(app_name, message) in the method 'onKeyDown', which is called when a key is pressed. Something like this can be done.

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)) {
        Log.v(app_name, "Back button pressed");
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Comment: But how about the different characters? For example like "@" "$" and so on. And also how to differentiate between capital letter and non capital letter? Because currently the KeyEvent can only be used for capital letter alphabets, hardware control buttons and numbers.

Comment: @perumal316 please avoid confusion between keyCode which represents a _key_ and _event.getUnicodeChar()_ that represents the glyph (or action) associated with this key and the current shift/alt/sym state.